# How to get employee gender by id number using php

Tags: php

I'm working on project where has Male & Female individual working shift. I only have data which contain their id number, name, email, etc except gender. But I need their gender for some specific features in my application. I can identify their gender by their number. They are like :

```
for male : 131011/131045/131123/141011/133288 // male id has 10,11,30,31 in middle
for female : 131211/131345/131288/133211/141266 //female id has 12,13,32,33 in middle
```

Is there any way to get their gender by PHP using their id number?
I've tried by some basic

```php
$x = 131166;
$y = 123219;

if($x % 2 == 0)
  echo "Male<br>";

if($y % 3 == 0)
  echo "FeMale<br>";
```

but its not working. Can anyone help? thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you just add a column for gender to the table?

Comment: What does modulus have to do with this? That just tells you whether the whole number is a multiple of 2 or 3.

Comment: I can't because data I have collected don't have their gender. I don't know who is male or female. I just identify their gender by their number. the data is so big i can't do it one by one

Comment: @Barmar i know I don't find any solution that's why

Comment: So you just try a random operation that has nothing to do with it, hoping that it will magically work?

Comment: Just ignore if you can't help. @barmar

Comment: I posted an answer to the question, isn't that helping? I just like to understand your thinking, maybe I can help you better if you explain why you thought `% 2` and `% 3` were possible solutions.

Comment: thanks for your ans bro, I m newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `substr()` to get the middle digits, then check it against your list of numbers.

```
$male = [10, 11, 30, 31];
$female = [12, 13, 32, 33];
$gender = substr($id, 2, 2);
if (in_array($gender, $male)) {
    echo "Male<br>";
} elseif (in_array($gender, $female)) {
    echo "Female<br>";
} else {
    echo "Bad gender code $gender<br>");
}
```